# Is it possible to create a SharePoint hosted list by SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, reactjs

I need to create a list inside the app which I can remove it when I delete the app from the site.

Comment: Why use SPFx when you can do it normally with SharePoint Hosted Add-in (SharePoint Hosted App) ?

Comment: Cause SharePoint hosted app is an **IFRAME** which is limited to work with other web parts in the page.

Comment: Then I think you are out of luck. SPFx don't have app isolation like SharePoint Hosted App. Your best bet is hidden the lists when provision and using ALM to remove the SPFx instead of using GUI.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe it would be an option to use the property bag?